# Loop through Map in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I have a JSON map in groovy

```
    {
          "Server1":{
              "Hostname":"YBDEL430OW02",
              "Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/",
              "Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"
          },
          "Server2":{
              "Hostname":"YBDEW430OW01",
              "Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/",
              "Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"
          },
          "Server3":{
              "Hostname":"YBDEL430OW01",
              "Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/",
              "Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"
          }
      }
```

Defined as

```
def object = {"Server1":{"Hostname":"YBDEL430OW02","Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/","Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"},"Server2":{"Hostname":"YBDEW430OW01","Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/","Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"},"Server3":{"Hostname":"YBDEL430OR07","Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/","Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"}}
```

I can access its data like this

```
println (object.server1.Hostname)

OUTPUT >> YBDEL430OW02

println (object.server2.Hostname)

OUTPUT >> YBDEW430OW01
```

But what i want is something like this so it can iterate it in a loop

```
      for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
         println (object.server[i].Hostname);
      }

OUTPUT >> YBDEL430OW02
OUTPUT >> YBDEL430OW01
OUTPUT >> YBDEL430OR07
```

Comment: You can iterate through properties of an object in groovy like this: `object.properties.each`, the docs for each are: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_maps

Comment: `object.each{ name, props -> ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full answer would be:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = '''  {
          "Server1":{
              "Hostname":"YBDEL430OW02",
              "Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/",
              "Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"
          },
          "Server2":{
              "Hostname":"YBDEW430OW01",
              "Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/",
              "Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"
          },
          "Server3":{
              "Hostname":"YBDEL430OW01",
              "Jboss_Home":"/weblogic/JBOSS/jboss-eap-6.4/",
              "Conf_File_Path":"/weblogic/apache-tomcat-8.5.34/Conf_File_Path"
          }
      }
'''

def jsonMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

jsonMap.each { key, value ->
    println value.Hostname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this solution:

```
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
    println object."Server${i+1}".Hostname
}
```

Comment: Yes i want something like this .. But this command is not working

Comment: No problem, I fixed it. There was no property "Server0" when the index is 0, so you must add +1 to it. See the updated code.